# Android development unable to find adb.exe

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools

It had been working for quite sometime. But suddenly stopped working, and received the error message

> Please ensure that adb is correctly located at
>   'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdkplatform-tools\adb.exe'

It is obvious that we missed a "\" between the "sdk" and "platform-tools" path.

Had been searching around in the web, but found no solution. Hope someone here can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u update ur sdk??

Comment: You can change the path of SDK from Windows-> Preferences -> Android

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you're using an IDE, so I'm assuming it's one of the Android SDK's scripts giving the error. In that case you'll want to double check the `ANDROID_HOME` path to ensure that the trailing backlash is present.

The easiest way is to correct search for and run "*Edit environment variables*", and then modify the and the `ANDROID_HOME` path as needed. After changing it a reboot will apply the new value.